# What is the maximum number of sites in Plone 4.1

Tags: plone, zope, max, sites

I would like to know how many sites / virtual hosts are allowed in a single installation of Plone. I am currently using a zeocluster installation. I am interested in the theoretical maximum i.e. infinite hardware, bandwidth etc.

Answer (score 3):

There's no theorical limit of Plone instances inside a single Zope instance. As its name says, Zope is an Object Publishing Environment and from Zope's point of view a Plone site is nothing more than an object like any other.

Comment: I can't help but add a quote from Laurence Rowe's reply to this question on plone-users: "By creating the sites inside a BTreeFolder2 the only limiting factor will be
the 48bit oid limit in FileStorage. So if we assume each site contains 1000
documents it will use something like 10000 objects, giving you a theoretical
limit of about 28 billion Plone sites.

The practical limit may be somewhat lower."

Comment: Ah thanks, i've already seen it from the mailing list. Even if I think that 28 billions is quite near to no-limit it's good to be precise :)

Answer (score 3):

If none are accessed then I'm guessing you can as many as you want. If they are accessed then your constraints are memory and cpu. We generally deploy our multisite deployments with separate mounts for every site which means there is a separate zodb cache for each site. This means that each site uses more RAM on each zope instance, but since this is infinite that isn't a problem for you :) CPU comes into play if all sites are accessed often. More requests, more cores are needed to avoid lagging requests. The third aspect is the database. Eventually if you're doing writes on those sites often enough, you'll max out your zodb connection. This is not easy to do since zodb requests are light. However if you did, then you could potentially get around this by using relstorage and having replication.